# Finding first recurring letter in each string of a given set

Tags: algorithm, c, strings, pointers

First input is the number of strings ex: 5
Second input is a set of strings ex: hello world how are you

Output the letter in the string ex: 'l' in string 1

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void find_first_recurring_letter(char **str,int r,int c);

int main()
{
    int r,i;
    printf("Enter the number of strings to be entered");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    /*dynamic allocation for str*/
    char **str=(char**)malloc(r*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        str[i]=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the string %d",i+1);
        gets(str[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        printf("%s\n",str[i]);
    find_first_recurring_letter(str,r,50);
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
       free(str[i]);
    return 0;
}


void find_first_recurring_letter(char **str,int r,int c)
{
    char *ptr,*sptr,ch[r];
    int indx[r];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        indx[i]=0;
        ch[i]='\0';
        for(ptr=&str[i][0];*ptr!='\0';ptr++)
        {
            for(sptr=&ptr[1];*sptr!='\0';sptr++)
            {
                if(*ptr==*sptr)
                    ch[i]= *ptr;
                    indx[i]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        if(ch[i]!='\0')
            printf("'%c' in string %d\n",ch[i],indx[i]+1);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should fix [This warnings/Errors](https://pastebin.com/raw/paFgQFDH)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Better names

The variable names are too short to be meaningful. It's common to use `i` as an index in `for`-loops, but `r` doesn't really tell us its purpose. Names like `number_of_strings` are self-descriptive, so we should use those.

## Unused variables

We never use `c` in `find_first_recurring_letter`, therefore we should remove the parameter altogether.

Strictly speaking, we also never use `indx[i]`. If `ch[i]` is '\0'`,`indx[i]`will be`1`(see "always use braces" below), and`1` otherwise, so we can replace

```
        printf("'%c' in string %d\n",ch[i],indx[i]+1);
```

by

```
        printf("'%c' in string %d\n", ch[i], 2);
```

without changing the programs logic.

## Simpler pointer logic

Instead of `ptr = &str[i][0]`, which is `ptr = &(*(str[i]))` use `ptr = str[i]`. Instead of `sptr = &ptr[1]`, just use `sptr = ptr`.

Again, we could call them `current` and `next` or similar.

By the way, *all* `indx[i]` are `1`  (see "unused variables" above and "always use braces" below). That doesn't sound right. Also keep in mind that [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are optional from C11 on.

## Get rid of additional memory

If we `printf` the recurring character, we can get rid of `ch` and `indx`:

```
            if(*ptr==*sptr)
                printf("....");
                indx[i]=1;
```

## Always use braces

Note that the code above contains a bug. `indx[1]` will be set to `1` regardless whether `*ptr == *sptr`. The indentation is misleading here.

You probably added `indx[i]` later and forgot the add the braces, so we should always use braces to make sure that bugs like this cannot happen.

If you don't want to use braces, use a code formatter. The indentation on the automatically formatted code will hint possible errors.

## Prefer late C99 declarations if possible

That way we can keep the scope of our variables short, e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_strings; ++i) {
    for(char *current = str[i]; *current != '\0'; current++) {
        for(char *next = current + 1; *next != '\0'; next++) {
            if(*current == *next) {
                printf("'%c' in string %d\n", *current, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's now impossible to use `next` outside of its loop. Also, we should try to initialize our variables whenever possible.

## Use `const type*` for inputs that are not supposed to change

That way we cannot accidentally modify your input values, e.g.

```
str[i][k] = '\0'
```

would not compile if `str` was `const char**`.

## Check `malloc`'s return

We should really check whether `malloc` returns `NULL`.

## Split functions

`find_first_recurring_letter` doesn't follow its name completely. We find the first recurring letter on a set of strings on a per-string basis. That sounds perfect for a split:

```
const char * find_first_recurring_letter(const char * haystack) {
    for(const char * current = haystack; *current != '\0'; current++) {
        for(const char * next = current + 1; *next != '\0'; next++) {
            if(*current == *next) {
                return current;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void find_first_recurring_letters(const char ** strings, int number_of_strings) {
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_strings; i++) {
        const char * result = find_first_recurring_letter(strings[i]);

        if(result) {
            printf("'%c' in string %d\n", *result, i);
        }
    }
}
```

We can now use `find_first_recurring_letter` on any null-terminated string. We're able to ***reuse*** functionality. Note that both functions are very easy to check by hand.

Comment: but is there a better way of solving this problem @Zeta

Comment: @katty there are other algorithms with \$\mathcal O(n \log k)\$ time and  \$\mathcal O(k)\$ additional space (where k is the number of distinct characters), and a radix-like one with \$\mathcal O(n)\$ time and  \$\mathcal O(2 ^\text{sizeof(char)})\$ space. But those are _other_ algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

@Zeta's answer is very good but I'd go ahead and improve the code by creating a few functions to improve readability:

```
void allocMemoryForStrings(char** arrayOfStrings, int numOfStrings){
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfStrings; i++){
        arrayOfStrings[i] = malloc(sizeof(*arrayOfStrings[i]) * 50);
    }
}

void printStrings(char** arrayOfStrings, int numOfStrings){
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfStrings; i++){
        printf("%s\n", arrayOfStrings[i]);
    }
}

void freeStrings(char** arrayOfStrings, int numOfStrings){
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfStrings; i++){
       free(arrayOfStrings[i]);
    }
}
```

P.S.: The code might need some tweaks to compile/work. Use it as a reference.

Comment: *"some tweaks"*? You didn't rename `str`  or `r` in your second and third example, and `i` wasn't declared at all.

Comment: @Zeta you're absolutely right. I've corrected that and also changed the function names to cameCase.

Comment: `arrayOfStrings[i] = (char*) malloc(50 * sizeof(char));`  ---> cast not needed.  Also, consider using the size of the reference type and not an explicit type.:  `arrayOfStrings[i] = malloc(sizeof *arrayOfStrings[i] * 50);`.  Easy to code. review and maintain.

Comment: @luizfzs Curious, do you find `sizeof(*arrayOfStrings[i])` easier to read than without parens: `sizeof *arrayOfStrings[i]`?

Comment: @chux, I find it easier to get what is being `sizeof`'ed.